# Python: Blocking issues with a queue and threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, queue, web.py

I'm having a strange issue with Python queues and threading.

I have a web.py application that schedules jobs, and as such has a `global incoming_queue = Queue(maxsize=10)`.

I have a url and a GET handler that adds to the queue (I also add to a list because I need to know the contents of the queue):

```
class ProcessRequest:
    def GET(self):
        global incoming_queue, incoming_jobs
        if incoming_queue.full():
            print "Queue is full"
            return web.InternalError("Queue is full, please try submitting later.")
        else:
            job_id = getNextInt()
            req_folder = "req" + str(job_id)
            incoming_queue.put(job_id)
            incoming_jobs.append(job_id)
            print "Received request, assigning Drop Folder {0}".format(req_folder)
            web.header('Drop-Folder', req_folder)
            return req_folder
```

I also run a thread to handle the jobs:

```
def processJobs():
    global incoming_queue, incoming_jobs, current_job, finished_jobs
    while True:
        print "Job processor thread active"
        current_job = incoming_queue.get(block=True)
        incoming_jobs.remove(current_job)
        print "Processing job {0}".format(current_job)
        # Do stuff here
        print "Job processor thread ready for next job"
    print "Job processor thread finished"
```

I run the following when I start the program:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    job_processor_thread = threading.Thread(target=processJobs)
    job_processor_thread.start()
    app.run()
```

I then call the URL that adds to the queue. Using another url, I was able to check that the item was indeed added to the list, and adding the following code to the GET method of the original url handler (`print incoming_queue.get()`), I verified that the item was indeed being added to the queue.

The job handling thread just blocks at `current_job = incoming_queue.get(block=True)`. This is intended. However, it never unblocks, even when an item is added to the queue. It simply stays blocked forever.

Why is that? It's almost like it has a separate copy of the queue object.

**Edit:** Per Martin's suggestion, I decided to try and see what object was being referenced in the GET method, and the processJobs method.

`processJobs(): <Queue.Queue instance at 0x7f32b6958a70>`
`GET(): <Queue.Queue instance at 0x7f32b5ec5368>`

Yes, they are different, but why?

**EDIT #2**: Here is the entire script for reference:

```
'''
Created on Apr 20, 2015

@author: chris
'''
import web
import time
import threading
import json
from Queue import Queue, Empty
import os

urls = (
        '/request', 'ProcessRequest',
        '/status', 'CheckStatus',
    )

current_job_thread = threading.Thread()

app = web.application(urls, globals())

incoming_jobs = []
incoming_queue = Queue(maxsize=10)

current_job = None

finished_jobs = []

next_int = 0

def getNextInt():
    global next_int, incoming_queue
    the_int = next_int
    next_int += 1
    return the_int

class ProcessRequest:
    def GET(self):
        global incoming_queue, incoming_jobs
        if incoming_queue.full():
            print "Queue is full"
            return web.InternalError("Queue is full, please try submitting later.")
        else:
            job_id = getNextInt()
            req_folder = "req" + str(job_id)
            print incoming_queue
            incoming_queue.put(job_id)
            incoming_jobs.append(job_id)
            print "Received request, assigning Drop Folder {0}".format(req_folder)
            web.header('Drop-Folder', req_folder)
            return req_folder

class CheckStatus:
    def GET(self):
        global incoming_queue, incoming_jobs, current_job, finished_jobs
        if str(web.input().jobid) == 'all':
            # Construct JSON to return
            web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            return {'In Queue': incoming_jobs,
                            'Currently Processing': current_job,
                            'Finished': finished_jobs
                    }
        try:
            jobid = int(web.input().jobid)
        except ValueError:
            jobid = -1
        print jobid
        if jobid in finished_jobs:
            file_string = "results{0}.json".format(jobid)
            try:
                json_file = open(file_string)
                finished_jobs.remove(jobid)
                os.remove(file_string)
                web.header('Process-Status', 'Complete')
                web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                return json.load(json_file)
            except IOError:
                web.header('Process-Status', 'Complete, but failed to retrieve file, saving')
                return ""

        elif jobid is current_job:
            web.header('Process-Status', 'Processing')
        elif jobid in incoming_jobs:
            web.header('Process-Status', 'In Queue')
        else:
            web.header('Process-Status', 'Unknown')
        return ""         

def processJobs():
    global incoming_queue, incoming_jobs, current_job, finished_jobs
    while True:
        print incoming_queue
        print "Job processor thread active"
        current_job = incoming_queue.get(block=True)
        incoming_jobs.remove(current_job)
        print "Processing job {0}".format(current_job)
        # Do magical Spark stuff here
        time.sleep(10)  # Simulate a Spark Job
        finished_jobs.append(current_job)
        current_job = None
        print "Job processor thread ready for next job"
    print "Job processor thread finished"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    job_processor_thread = threading.Thread(target=processJobs)
    job_processor_thread.start()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Martin's direction, I was able to solve the issue using the idea from here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webpy/u-cfL7jLywo.

Basically, web.py recreates the global variables when a request is made, so we cannot use global variables if we want to share data between the framework and other threads. The solution is to create another module, create a class in that module, and add the variable definitions to there. Here is what I ended up with:

jobqueue.py:

```
'''
Created on Apr 23, 2015

@author: chris
'''
import Queue

class JobManagement:
    incoming_queue = Queue.Queue(maxsize=10)
    incoming_jobs = []
    current_job = None
    finished_jobs = []
```

main.py:

```
'''
Created on Apr 20, 2015

@author: chris
'''
import web
import time
import threading
import json
from Queue import Queue, Empty
import os
from jobqueue import JobManagement

urls = (
        '/request', 'ProcessRequest',
        '/status', 'CheckStatus',
    )

app = web.application(urls, globals())

next_int = 0

def getNextInt():
    global next_int
    the_int = next_int
    next_int += 1
    return the_int

class ProcessRequest:
    def GET(self):
        if JobManagement.incoming_queue.full():
            print "Queue is full"
            return web.InternalError("Queue is full, please try submitting later.")
        else:
            job_id = getNextInt()
            req_folder = "req" + str(job_id)
            print JobManagement.incoming_queue
            JobManagement.incoming_queue.put(job_id)
            JobManagement.incoming_jobs.append(job_id)
            print "Received request, assigning Drop Folder {0}".format(req_folder)
            web.header('Drop-Folder', req_folder)
            return req_folder

class CheckStatus:
    def GET(self):
        if str(web.input().jobid) == 'all':
            # Construct JSON to return
            web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            return {'In Queue': JobManagement.incoming_jobs,
                            'Currently Processing': JobManagement.current_job,
                            'Finished': JobManagement.finished_jobs
                    }
        try:
            jobid = int(web.input().jobid)
        except ValueError:
            jobid = -1
        print jobid
        if jobid in JobManagement.finished_jobs:
            file_string = "results{0}.json".format(jobid)
            try:
                json_file = open(file_string)
                JobManagement.finished_jobs.remove(jobid)
                os.remove(file_string)
                web.header('Process-Status', 'Complete')
                web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                return json.load(json_file)
            except IOError:
                web.header('Process-Status', 'Complete, but failed to retrieve file, saving')
                return ""

        elif jobid is JobManagement.current_job:
            web.header('Process-Status', 'Processing')
        elif jobid in JobManagement.incoming_jobs:
            web.header('Process-Status', 'In Queue')
        else:
            web.header('Process-Status', 'Unknown')
        return ""         

def processJobs():
    while True:
        print JobManagement.incoming_queue
        print "Job processor thread active"
        JobManagement.current_job = JobManagement.incoming_queue.get(block=True)
        JobManagement.incoming_jobs.remove(JobManagement.current_job)
        print "Processing job {0}".format(JobManagement.current_job)
        # Do magical Spark stuff here
        time.sleep(10)  # Simulate a Spark Job
        JobManagement.finished_jobs.append(JobManagement.current_job)
        JobManagement.current_job = None
        print "Job processor thread ready for next job"
    print "Job processor thread finished"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print JobManagement.incoming_queue
    job_processor_thread = threading.Thread(target=processJobs)
    job_processor_thread.start()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test your assumption that they are different queues simply by printing the object:

```
def processJobs():
    global incoming_queue, incoming_jobs, current_job, finished_jobs
    print incoming_queue # print something like <__main__.Queue instance at 0x7f556d93f830>


class ProcessRequest:
    def GET(self):
        global incoming_queue, incoming_jobs
        print incoming_queue # print something like <__main__.Queue instance at 0x7f556d93f830>
```

Ensure the memory addresses (0x7f556d93f830) match.

You never mention if you are using a framework to handle web requests, so it may be that the framework is doing some forking which cause your queues to be separate instances.

On a side note, you may want to consider Redis or beanstalk as a queue - these are really simple to use, and your queues will persist even when your restart your app.

Comment: I mentioned I was using web.py. I'll try this out and report back.

Comment: Interesting, they are indeed different instances.

Comment: Do you have `incoming_queue = Queue()` in multiple locations? If only one location, how is that location run?

Comment: It is in the main script, I'll include the whole thing in an edit so you can see.

Comment: I'm not familiar `web.py` lifecycle, but it seems that making a GET request will re-import your script, which causes `incoming_queue = Queue()` to be run again. You can test this out by putting a print statement right above where the Queue instance is created, and making a request. You will see your printed output twice.

Comment: I put a print statement right above the line where I create the queue and it only prints once. This is bizzare.

Comment: If you make a request, it should print a second time.

Comment: Yeah, it's happening on the request, but only once.

Comment: You will find the solution here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webpy/u-cfL7jLywo. You need to instantiate the queue in a separate module.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was suspecting. I'll try it out and let you know if it works.

Comment: Beautiful, I fixed it by adding the global variables to a class in a separate module and calling them from there. I'll post it as an answer.